# Java 8 JIT thread seems like falling into infinite loop

Tags: java, jvm, java-8, jit

I wrote a server application in Java 8, and running it with java 1.8.0u25.

It works fine for the first several hours, but after it gets about 5k~10k requests, a thread of the VM process uses 100% of one of the CPUs.

So I tried `jstack` for the VM process to check what the problematic thread was, and it showed that the thread(thread id was 14303=0x37df) was "C2 CompilerThread0":

```
"C2 CompilerThread0" #6 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00002aaabc12a000 nid=0x37df runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
```

And with `jstack -m`, the stack trace of the thread was as the following:

```
----------------- 14303 -----------------
0x00002b99b67693c3  _ZN16PhaseMacroExpand27process_users_of_allocationEP8CallNode + 0x2a3
0x00002b99b676ec3b  _ZN16PhaseMacroExpand23eliminate_allocate_nodeEP12AllocateNode + 0x1cb
0x00002b99b676ee65  _ZN16PhaseMacroExpand21eliminate_macro_nodesEv + 0x1a5
0x00002b99b6772769  _ZN16PhaseMacroExpand18expand_macro_nodesEv + 0x19
0x00002b99b640b01b  _ZN7Compile8OptimizeEv + 0xa6b
0x00002b99b640c53c  _ZN7CompileC1EP5ciEnvP10C2CompilerP8ciMethodibbb + 0x13bc
0x00002b99b635f9c8  _ZN10C2Compiler14compile_methodEP5ciEnvP8ciMethodi + 0x198
0x00002b99b6414c6a  _ZN13CompileBroker25invoke_compiler_on_methodEP11CompileTask + 0xc8a
0x00002b99b6417650  _ZN13CompileBroker20compiler_thread_loopEv + 0x620
0x00002b99b69a2e8f  _ZN10JavaThread17thread_main_innerEv + 0xdf
0x00002b99b69a2fbc  _ZN10JavaThread3runEv + 0x11c
0x00002b99b6860d48  _ZL10java_startP6Thread + 0x108
```

And every time I tried `jstack -m`, the stack trace of this thread was all the same, but the number beside the method(program counter?) at the top of the stack `_ZN16PhaseMacroExpand27process_users_of_allocationEP8CallNode` was `0x290`, `0x2b1`, `0x2a3`, or `0x29f`.

`C2 CompilerThread0` looks like a thread doing JIT compilation, and the stack trace seems like it fell into an infinite loop or something.

I wonder if this could be a bug of JIT compiler of JVM. If it is, how can I specify which method of my application makes the JVM crazy and how can I solve(or work around) this problem? I tried `-XX:+PrintCompilation` option, but it did not help much because it didn't show which thread compiled which method.
If it is not a problem of JVM, what could make this thing happen?

Comment: This seems to belong to the escape analysis so disabling it via `-XX:-DoEscapeAnalysis` might hotfix the problem. There is the option `-XX:+PrintEliminateAllocations` to see its effects, however, it requires a debug build of the JVM.

Comment: If it is a bug, I suggest trying Java 8 update 31 or update 40 as this may have been fixed.

Comment: I tried Java 8 u31 following @PeterLawrey's advice, but the same problem is happening again..

Comment: do you have reproducible snippet or a tracking bug number and did the 51 minor release on 8 fix it ?

Comment: @PeterLawrey do you know by any chance whether the issue described here was actually submitted and fixed yet? I tried searching jdk bug tracker, but found nothing directly corresponding to the symptoms described here.

Comment: @tu_ru no, but trying with a newer update (which was available at the time) is often a simple way to find it has been fixed already (and thus whether it is a know/fixed bug)

Comment: I am seeing this on openjdk 1.8.0_181-b13 on CentOS. Not 100% sure that its exactly this, but process has almost nothing to do but take 100% CPU.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It indeed looks like a JIT compiler bug, presumably in allocation elimination optimization.
Try running with `-XX:-EliminateAllocations` JVM option.

You may also add `-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+LogCompilation` to produce detailed compilation log with a separate output file per compiler thread.