# 100% CPU usage by Java

Tags: java, linux, multithreading, centos, cpu-usage

I'm facing an issue that occurs randomly and causes a 100% CPU usage. I've found the PID of the thread which is actually using CPU.

```
Main PID: 22777
Thread PID: 22793
```

From `top -H -u user`

```
PID   USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
22793 user      25   0 2640m  16m  14m R 98.8  0.4   5134:31 java
22480 user      25   0  7920  364  360 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 cat
22777 user      18   0 2640m  16m  14m S  0.0  0.4   0:00.00 java
22779 user      18   0 2640m  16m  14m S  0.0  0.4   0:03.34 java
22780 user      15   0 2640m  16m  14m S  0.0  0.4   0:46.76 java
22781 user      15   0 2640m  16m  14m S  0.0  0.4   0:00.49 java
{...}
```

From `jstack -J-d64 -m 22777`

```
{...}
----------------- 22793 -----------------
0x00002b9edcd4c5a0      _ZN12Dependencies25find_finalizable_subclassEP5Klass + 0x150
0x00002b9edcc5a8ee      _ZN15ciInstanceKlass24has_finalizable_subclassEv + 0xbe
0x00002b9edcb9f83e      _ZN12GraphBuilder23call_register_finalizerEv + 0x9e
0x00002b9edcba62a5      _ZN12GraphBuilder13method_returnEP11Instruction + 0x295
0x00002b9edcbac85f      _ZN12GraphBuilder27iterate_bytecodes_for_blockEi + 0x6cf
0x00002b9edcba9c4b      _ZN12GraphBuilder18iterate_all_blocksEb + 0x14b
0x00002b9edcbaa5e6      _ZN12GraphBuilder15try_inline_fullEP8ciMethodbN9Bytecodes4CodeEP11Instruction + 0x996
0x00002b9edcbaa7df      _ZN12GraphBuilder10try_inlineEP8ciMethodbN9Bytecodes4CodeEP11Instruction + 0x11f
0x00002b9edcbab912      _ZN12GraphBuilder6invokeEN9Bytecodes4CodeE + 0xbb2
0x00002b9edcbac83d      _ZN12GraphBuilder27iterate_bytecodes_for_blockEi + 0x6ad
0x00002b9edcba9c4b      _ZN12GraphBuilder18iterate_all_blocksEb + 0x14b
0x00002b9edcbaa5e6      _ZN12GraphBuilder15try_inline_fullEP8ciMethodbN9Bytecodes4CodeEP11Instruction + 0x996
0x00002b9edcbaa7df      _ZN12GraphBuilder10try_inlineEP8ciMethodbN9Bytecodes4CodeEP11Instruction + 0x11f
0x00002b9edcbab912      _ZN12GraphBuilder6invokeEN9Bytecodes4CodeE + 0xbb2
0x00002b9edcbac83d      _ZN12GraphBuilder27iterate_bytecodes_for_blockEi + 0x6ad
0x00002b9edcba9bf2      _ZN12GraphBuilder18iterate_all_blocksEb + 0xf2
0x00002b9edcbae7a7      _ZN12GraphBuilderC1EP11CompilationP7IRScope + 0x527
0x00002b9edcbb7127      _ZN7IRScopeC1EP11CompilationPS_iP8ciMethodib + 0x1e7
0x00002b9edcbb723f      _ZN2IRC1EP11CompilationP8ciMethodi + 0x9f
0x00002b9edcb9625b      _ZN11Compilation9build_hirEv + 0xdb
0x00002b9edcb9661e      _ZN11Compilation19compile_java_methodEv + 0x6e
0x00002b9edcb9674e      _ZN11Compilation14compile_methodEv + 0x4e
0x00002b9edcb96abe      _ZN11CompilationC1EP16AbstractCompilerP5ciEnvP8ciMethodiP10BufferBlob + 0x25e
0x00002b9edcb97869      _ZN8Compiler14compile_methodEP5ciEnvP8ciMethodi + 0xa9
0x00002b9edccea43a      _ZN13CompileBroker25invoke_compiler_on_methodEP11CompileTask + 0xc9a
0x00002b9edcceb3e6      _ZN13CompileBroker20compiler_thread_loopEv + 0x5d6
0x00002b9edd29ebcf      _ZN10JavaThread17thread_main_innerEv + 0xdf
0x00002b9edd29ecfc      _ZN10JavaThread3runEv + 0x11c
0x00002b9edd153048      _ZL10java_startP6Thread + 0x108
{...}
```

It looks like a JVM bug when compiling something.
    java version "1.8.0_51"
    Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_51-b16)
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.51-b03, mixed mode)

```
CentOS 5.5
Kernel: 2.6.18-194.el5
```

Other processes aren't being affected, but the Java process is completely unresponsive. It also occurs at other CentOS servers, but not at Oracle Linux servers.

Comment: Have you tried upgrading to the latest Java 8 (Update 102)?

Comment: Do you have any problems like other applications being unresponsive/slow? 100% CPU usage itself isn't bad as long as other processes are not negatively affected - why should a process that can be sped up by using all available CPU cycles not use them?

Comment: How repeatable?  Would it be worth your while to use some combination of trial-and-error and logging to try to isolate the piece of code that causes the problem?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I can't update Java at the moment.

Comment: @Thomas Other processes aren't being affected, but the Java process is completely unresponsive. It also occurs at other CentOS servers, but not at Oracle Linux servers.

Comment: That's some information that should be added to your question. Don't count on others to get that piece of information from the comments.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas. I've edited my question.

Comment: Have you tried (if possible) to terminate some of the other java processes, like PIDs 22780, 22781? What happens when you terminate these one?

Comment: I can't terminate other java processess. It's a production server.

Comment: Related to this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28196233/java-8-jit-thread-seems-like-falling-into-infinite-loop

Comment: @StephenC Maybe. But in my case, is C1 instead C2 compiler.

Comment: I am observing same problem on CentOS. Initially thought that mongodb java driver was problem, but i removed it and the problem is still in place.